# DMC compiler - "Floating point not loaded" error in C

Tags: c, floating-point, runtime-error, scanf

When I am trying to take input of `float` or `double` type in my program it gives me the runtime error **"Floating point is not loaded"**...
I'm using the **DMC compiler**

In this program I am trying to take input from user, everything works fine. Instead of the price input, I've defined price in structure of double type and the program gives me the runtime error of **floating point not loaded**. I searched the internet but didn't find anything.

What causes this error and how do I resolve it?

here's the error screen : 
[image: SCREENSHOT of ERROR]

here's the code :-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node {
    char isbn[16];
    char title[60];
    char author[40];
    double price;
    int issueSTATUS;
    long count;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *bookdb;

void display();

void main() {
    bookdb = NULL;
    append();
    display();
    getch();
}

void append() {
    struct node *temp = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("Enter the Book ISBN : ");
    scanf("%s", temp->isbn);
    printf("Enter the Book Name : ");
    scanf("%s", temp->title);
    printf("Enter the Book Author Name : ");
    scanf("%s", temp->author);
    printf("Enter the Book Price : ");
    scanf("%f", &temp->price); //<--------------------------here's the problem---------------------
    temp->issueSTATUS = 0;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if(bookdb == NULL) {
        bookdb = temp;
        bookdb->count++;
    } else {
        struct node *iterator = bookdb;
        while(iterator->next != NULL) {
            iterator = iterator->next;
        }
        iterator->next = temp;
    }
}

void display() {
    struct node *temp = bookdb;
    while(temp->next != NULL) {
        printf("|%-16s|%-60s|%-20s|$%-5.2f|");
        if(temp->issueSTATUS == 1) {
            printf("YES\n");
        } else {
            printf("NO\n");
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("|%-16s|%-60s|%-20s|%-5.2f|");
    if(temp->issueSTATUS == 1) {
        printf("YES\n");
    } else {
        printf("NO\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Compile with `-Wall -Wextra` and the compiler will tell you

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags. If you program in C then don't add the C++ tag (they are two very different languages). And the `dmcs` tag could be more closely linked with the Mono C# compiler than the "DMC compiler" (whatever compiler that is, do you mean the Digital Mars C compiler?).

Comment: If you use the Digital Mars C compiler (why? Are you targeting an old DOS system? It seems highly outdated otherwise) then [this reference](https://digitalmars.com/ctg/sc.html) should be very helpful. Check out the `-f`, `-fd` and `-ff` switches.

Comment: Please use Copy&paste to add text output as text into the question. No need to show graphics of a nearly empty screen.

Comment: I don't know your compiler. But some compilers provide different versions of C standard lib with or without support for floating point types. It seems your program was build using such a smaller limited library. You should consult the compiler's manual to check for proper settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check if your DMC version has the use of floating-point types enabled. There is a high chance that this will cause the issue as per documentation:

> Floating point not loaded
>
> The program attempts to perform floating point operations, but the floating point run-time system is not linked. Run OBJ2ASM on the object file to ensure that the external reference _fltused was generated. Otherwise, remove the floating point operation.
>
> Source: https://digitalmars.com/ctg/runtime.html

Second, if floating-point types are enabled, consider:

```
scanf("%f", &temp->price);
```

The `%f` format specifier in `scanf()` expect an argument of type `* float` but `&temp->price` is of type `*double`.

Use `%lf` for `double` instead:

```
scanf("%lf", &temp->price);
```

---

Side notes:

1. What is the purpose of `printf("|%-16s|%-60s|%-20s|%-5.2f|");` in `display()`? Format string attack? This use of `printf` isn´t correct. Every format specifier requires to have an appropriate corresponding argument.
2. The return type of `main` shall be `int`, not `void`.
3. Consider to update to a more up-to-date compiler, like f.e. GCC with [MingW-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) on Windows.

Comment: In general that is true, but how would this be able to cause the error? The number was not even entered yet

Comment: @Gerhardh I guess, It doesn´t have to be entered. Since the call to `scanf()` is corrupt by the mismatch of format specifier to argument, the execution itself causes an error. But that is of course just an assumption. I don´t know how DMC is constructed. At least OP shall try if it works. There is high chance that it will.

Comment: I know that this is UB and in theory everything can happen. But for practical purposes there is no reason why that pointer should be dereferenced without having converted any input value. Of course the OP should fix these 3 issues. But that will not solve the problem.

Comment: If it's indeed the Digital Mars C compiler, the documentation for it prominently mentions the x87 coprocessor and that special command-line switches are needed to enable generation of code for it. While your answer is correct, I would argue that it's more likely that the compiler simply haven't enabled floating point handling in the generated code, and `scanf` just exits when it detects non-floating point together with the `%f` format.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, you both were correct. I found a documentation of Digital Mars that this diagnostic message belongs to a not linked floating-point run-time system as quoted in the edit.

Comment: @Gerhardh Yes, you were correct with your assumption. The cause of the issue seems without doubt to be a not linked floating-point run-time system as quoted in the edit.